# Is it feasible to display hyperlink or button on JQgrid Add/edit dialogbox

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is it feasible to show hyperlink on add/edit dialog box plugin?
Hyperlink is displayed in grid but is not visible on the dialogbox.

For detailed code and screenshots please refer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665823/jqgrid-hyperlink-not-visible-in-add-edit-dialogbox-but-visible-in-column-of-the

Comment: I read the old question before and this new question, but I don't understand how you want the "Add/Edit" dialog should looks like. "Add/Edit" dialog include only editable columns (see [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665823/jqgrid-hyperlink-not-visible-in-add-edit-dialogbox-but-visible-in-column-of-the)). How you want to edit the links or at least how and where to display?

Comment: Oleg, Thanks for the reply! On Add/edit box it should be placed anywhere, preferabally in the row of the "Submit - cancel" buttons, before submit button. The links will not be aditable. The functionality used by these links will be related preview the file listed in first column etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the information which you need **manually**. You can do this inside of for example [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) or [afterShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) as a part of Edit/Add options. Here is the code example

```
{ // edit options
    recreateForm: true,
    beforeShowForm: function(form) {
        var nameColumnField = $('#tr_Name', form);
        $('<tr class="FormData" id="tr_AddInfo"><td "+
            "class="CaptionTD ui-widget-content"><b>Additional Information:</b>"+
            "</td></tr>').insertAfter (nameColumnField);
    }
}
```

[Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomFormEdit1.htm) you can find old demo which shows one additional field in the Add dialog and insert additional the row with additional information in the dialog.