# jqGrid, how to add a row in any position inside the grid via modal form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is there any way to do that?
I use jqGrid [form editing feature](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing) to populate my grid. But jqGrid only permits to add a row on top or bottom position inside the grid. What I want to do is be able to previously select the desired position on the grid (by clicking in any existing row) and then add a row above or below that selected row.

Sorry for my poor english. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is possible and is not so complex. Look at the very [old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomFormEdit1.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5745168/315935). If you have the column with `name: 'myColName'`, and you want to insert any information in the edit or add form *after* the information about the column, you can just inset the row of data inside. The form contain `<table>`. So you should insert the `<tr>` having one or two child `<td>` elements (the cell for the label and the cell for the data). To be conform with other data in the form you should use `class="FormData"` for the `<tr>` element. The first `<td>` element (in the column for the labels) should has `class="CaptionTD ui-widget-content"` and the second `<td>` element (in the column for the data for the input of modification) should has `class="DataTD ui-widget-content"`:

```
{ // edit options
    recreateForm: true,
    beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
        var $formRow = $form.find('#tr_Name'); // 'Name' in the column name
                        // after which you want insert the information
        $('<tr class="FormData"><td class="CaptionTD ui-widget-content">' +
             '<b>Label:</b>' + // in the line can be any custom HTML code
             '</td><td class="DataTD ui-widget-content">' +
             '<span></span>' + // in the line can be any custom HTML code
             '</td></tr>').insertAfter($formRow);
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**: OK, now I understand what you want. The problem is that `addRowData` will be called for adding of new row with the option [addedrow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) of [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow). So if you use `reloadAfterSubmit: false` option you can add the new row either as `'first'` or as the `'last'` in the grid. To be able to use `'after'` or `'before'` parameter of `addRowData` the method `addRowData` must be called with one more parameter which specify the id of the row before which (or after which) the new row will be inserted.

At the first look it seems that only with respect of modification of the source code of jqGrid your requirement can be implemented. In reality you can do implement your requirements with very small code and *without modification of the source code of jqGrid*. I suggest the following:

You can save the pointer to the original implementation of `addRowData` in a variable and overwrite it 
with your implementation:

```
var oldAddRowData = $.fn.jqGrid.addRowData;
$.jgrid.extend({
    addRowData: function (rowid, rdata, pos, src) {
        if (pos === 'afterSelected' || pos === 'beforeSelected') {
            if (typeof src === 'undefined' && this[0].p.selrow !== null) {
                src = this[0].p.selrow;
                pos = (pos === 'afterSelected') ? 'after' : 'before';
            } else {
                pos = (pos === 'afterSelected') ? 'last' : 'first';
            }
        }
        return oldAddRowData.call(this, rowid, rdata, pos, src);
    }
});
```

The code above introduce two new options of `addRowData`: `'afterSelected'` and `'beforeSelected'`. If you include the code before creating of jqGrid the grid will be created using your custom `addRowData`, so you can use new `addedrow: 'afterSelected'` or `addedrow: 'beforeSelected'` as the options of Add form.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditingWithAddAfterSelected.htm) shows live that the suggestion work. You should don't look at many other code of the demo. The current implementation of form editing don't support local editing, but in I used in the demo just old code which do this. So the total code of the demo is relatively long, but the part which I want to demonstrate you can easy find inside.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question Oleg. But I think this is not exactly what I want.

I need to insert a row inside the grid after the form is submitted, but I have to be able to insert that row in any position inside the grid. It is similar to **addRowData** method does.

Comment: @RicardoDuarte: Now I understand what you need and I updated my answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot for helping me in this issue. You're doing valuable work. I will implement your suggestion and come back here to post the result.

Comment: @RicardoDuarte: You are welcome! I am glad to read that I could help you!