# how to add new row in jqgrid in middle of grid

Tags: jqgrid

jqGrid 4.3 allows to add new row using inline edit.

Inline navigator demo in http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html
Shows that after add command grid is scrolled to top and added row appears in top of grid.
This is confusing.

How to force added row to appear before current row?

I posted this as feature request in  http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/force-added-row-in-inline-edit-to-appear-before-current-row/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8437659/315935) I suggested to extend `addRowData` method to support new 'afterSelected' and 'beforeSelected' values (additionally to existing 'first', 'last', 'before' and 'after') of the `position` parameter. I shown one can overwrite (subclass) the original `addRowData` method to add the support without writing the full code of `addRowData`.

In the corresponding [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditingWithAddAfterSelected.htm) I demonstrated how one could use the feature in case of the usage of [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing).

In the same way we can solve the problem in the [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav) method too. [The new demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/inlineNav-addAfterSelected.htm) demonstrate this.

The corresponding code is practically the copy of the codes from the answer.

```js
var oldAddRowData = $.fn.jqGrid.addRowData;

$.jgrid.extend({
    addRowData: function (rowid, rdata, pos, src) {
        if (pos === 'afterSelected' || pos === 'beforeSelected') {
            if (typeof src === 'undefined' && this[0].p.selrow !== null) {
                src = this[0].p.selrow;
                pos = (pos === "afterSelected") ? 'after' : 'before';
            } else {
                pos = (pos === "afterSelected") ? 'last' : 'first';
            }
        }
        return oldAddRowData.call(this, rowid, rdata, pos, src);
    }
});

...
$("#list").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager', {addParams: {position: "afterSelected"}});
```

Probably I should post to [trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393) the corresponding suggestion to modify the original `addRowData` method with the described above features.

Comment: According to Tony reply in trirand forum it seems that those are already implemented in jqGrid. Which is best way to force added row to appear before current row in inline and form add modes ?

Comment: @Andrus: Please look at [my answer](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/force-added-row-in-inline-edit-to-appear-before-current-row/#p25427) to the post of Tony.

Comment: Oleg. Thank you very much. Context menu from toolbar you created shows inline navigator buttons as active if they are not active in jqgrid toolbar. How to fix this ?

Comment: @Andrus: I think one should just include additional test whether the toolbar button has `'ui-state-disabled'` class or not. I think your question is not about the problem discussed in the question/the answer. It's the subject of the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8491939/315935) and I will answer you therein.

Comment: @Oleg: can you look at this one, it is an extension of this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238092/jqgrid-extending-addrowdata

Comment: @Oleg : In 4.8.0 this causes exception `Cannot read property 'addRowData' of undefined` . Is this fix already included or how to fix ?

Comment: @Andrus: I tried the above code with free jqGrid 4.8 and I could not see any problem. I used of cause new option `inlineEditing: {position: "afterSelected"}` to specify `position` (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods#solution-of-the-problem-in-free-jqgrid-48)). Are you sure that the row is selected? Could you verify your code and open new question with the demo example if the problem will not solved? I will include the feature with `afterSelected` in the main code of free jqGrid. I forgot just about the feature.

Comment: @Andrus: I posted additional details in [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/19) which you posted.

Comment: @user3850805: Thank you! By the way, [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), my fork of jqGrid, includes the option "afterSelected" of `addRowData`. Thus one don't need to "subclass" `addRowData` if one use free jqGrid.