# jqGrid inline editing with dynamic scroll - scrolling issues

Tags: jqgrid, scroll, jqgrid-inlinenav

I'm using jqGrid with dynamic scrolling and I'd like to use the Inline editing with `inlineNav` incl. [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8518501/904846) which makes inline editing finaly useful.

I found dynamic scrolling problematic because not all rows are loaded (and rendered) and Inline editing methods goes wrong when scrolling. To avoid problems, user can't scroll out:

- can't scroll after selecting the row and then using add/edit
- can't scroll even without selecting the row, because with no selection, `first` position is applied (3rd video)
- can't scroll while adding/editing a row (one solution may be temporarily disabling the scroller)

Links:

- demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dmnc_net/tNGJn/
- scrolling with `beforeSelected`: http://youtu.be/osvwiykcuME
- scrolling with `first` and `last`: http://youtu.be/Du_TBrlrzSI
- scrolling without clicking any row: http://youtu.be/pCzpk1SvQNA

I've used these addRow position settings: `beforeSelected`, `first` and `last`; `before` and `after` are not working at all.

I'm thinking about solve this problem by patching `addRow` and `editRow` methods by telling them scroll position and handling loaded/unloaded "pages" when user has scrolled too far and selected record are unloaded. But I'm not sure if this is possible or it will be better to use modal add/edit dialogs.