# Jqgrid adding new blank row in inlineNav style

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I would like to create `Add` `Edit` `Save`   And `Delete` button below my JqGrid.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var lastSel = 0;
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url: '/SpeakerJqgrid/GridData/',
        editurl: "/SpeakerJqgrid/MyEdit/",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['SpeakerID', 'SpeakerName'],
        colModel: [
                      { name: 'SpeakerID', index: 'SpeakerID', width: 40, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: "35", maxlength: "50"} },
                      { name: 'SpeakerName', index: 'SpeakerName', width: 200, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: "35", maxlength: "50"} }
                 ],
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            if (id && id !== lastSel) {
                jQuery('#list').restoreRow(lastSel);
                lastSel = id;
            }
            jQuery('#list').editRow(id, true);
        },
        loadComplete: function () {
            //alert("Load Complete");
        },
        addRowData: function (rowid, rdata, pos, src) {
            alert("addRowData");
            if (pos === 'afterSelected' || pos === 'beforeSelected') {
                if (typeof src === 'undefined' && this[0].p.selrow !== null) {
                    src = this[0].p.selrow;
                    pos = (pos === "afterSelected") ? 'after' : 'before';
                } else {
                    pos = (pos === "afterSelected") ? 'last' : 'first';
                }
            }
            return oldAddRowData.call(this, rowid, rdata, pos, src);
        },

        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        sortname: 'SpeakerName',
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,            
        autowidth: true,
        autoheight: true,
        imgpath: '/scripts/themes/black-tie/images',
        caption: 'My first grid'
    })
    $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {edit:false,add:false,del:false,refresh:false,search:false});
    $("#list").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager', {
        edittext: "Edit",
        addtext: "Add",
        savetext: "Save",
        canceltext: "Cancel",
        addParams: { position: "afterSelected" }
    });
    }); 
</script>
```

By using upper code, My Grid show me buttons called `Add` `Edit` `Save`   And `Delete`.
But what problem is when I click those buttons, nothing happen.

I mean that I would like to create event which will fire when I click Add or Edit button.

Most of the examples I found is about adding new rows by using  [modal form](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing). But what I have to use is inline grid row adding style.

Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html Row Editing -> Custom Edit in the left menu

Comment: Thank for your suggestion @laroslav. I have found at Row Editing (new)--> Inline Navigator (new).But I still don't find js event which have to fire when I click " + " button.

Comment: at Custom Edit sample you may see those buttons attached to each row, for code see gridComplete event

Comment: Sorry, did not see word 'below' in the beginning of sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all there are no callback function `addRowData`. If you want to modify *the method* [addRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) to support 'afterSelected' or 'beforeSelected' you should follow my suggestion from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8437659/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8518501/315935) with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/inlineNav-addAfterSelected.htm).

Now about your main question. The [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav) method used internally [addRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#addrow) and [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) methods. So if the user click on "Add" or "Edit" button added by [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav) the [addRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#addrow) or [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) will be called. You can use `addParams` and `editParams` options of [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav) to change the default parameters of [addRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#addrow) or [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow). If you just need to specify your own  callback function which will be called when the user click on Add or Edit button you can use the following code:

```
$("#list").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager', {
    edittext: "Edit",
    addtext: "Add",
    savetext: "Save",
    canceltext: "Cancel",
    addParams: {
        position: "afterSelected",
        addRowParams: {
            // the parameters of editRow used to edit new row
            keys: true,
            oneditfunc: function (rowid) {
                alert("new row with rowid=" + rowid + " are added.");
            }
        }
    },
    editParams: {
        // the parameters of editRow
        key: true,
        oneditfunc: function (rowid) {
            alert("row with rowid=" + rowid + " is editing.");
        }
    }
});
```

Additionally you should probably remove the code of the `onSelectRow` callback if you need to use Edit button of `inlineNav`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Oleg, Finally, your suggestion and code solved my problem.

Comment: @Oleg: My solution works only when the position: "afterSelected" is removed. Why?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: I suppose because you don't added **modified version of `addRowData`** (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8437659/315935) referenced in the current my answer).