# Adding a new row in jqgrid with grouping and local data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a table with jqGrid. I am able to add a new row at the end / first position of the table using :

```
jQuery('#tableId').jqGrid('addRow', parameters);
```

where parameters are:

```
var parameters = { rowID: 'new_row', position: 'last', useDefValues: true}
```

However, I have a table with grouping enabled. And I want to insert a row under a certain grouping (always the last row at that group, but can be the middle in the table, depending where the grouping is). The current workaround I have is to modify the data and the options so it will redraw the whole table, but I don't want that due to performance issue. I am interested in inserting a row inside a certain grouping.

Is this possible? I looked at a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433499/jqgrid-how-to-add-a-row-in-any-position-inside-the-grid-via-modal-form), however it adds a new row after or before a selected row. Is it possible to insert a row after a certain row / inside a certain group?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's unclear how you use jqGrid. Do you use server side paging or not? Which fork of jqGrid and in which version you use? By the way the usage of `rowID: 'new_row'` is not good. Default value `rowID: undefined` is better because it generates *unique* rowid. Reloading of jqGrid means reloading of **the current page** only. So it works typically quickly enough. How many rows and columns you have in the grid and on the page?